# Google Sheets Query same data from numerous columns

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

We have Employee training data in a Google 'Form Response' spreadsheet which ranges from A1 to JQ1000. This spreadsheet is automatically populated when a Goggle Form is completed but it is difficult to look at so I want to tidy it up.

The Form Response spreadsheet is populated with the Training Event, the date of the event and the employees who attended that event. To tidy it up I thought it best to use Transpose(Query but an employee's name might appear several times in different columns and different rows. I don't want to have to write `'Select * WHERE C = 'David Bowie' OR D = 'David Bowie' OR E = 'David Bowie'"` and so on out to column JQ. Can someone help me with a simpler formula?

Comment: Sounds like you need to fix your data and then it should be a simple query. If the data is a mess, the query will also become the same.

Comment: Sorry - I have re-worded my question

Comment: Maybe you can add a column using `=join(C2:JQ)`?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it for example like this:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY({A1:JQ, TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:JQ),,999^99))}, 
 "where Col"&COLUMN(JQ1)+1&" contains 'Sara'", 0), 999^99, COLUMNS(A1:JQ))
```

[image: 0]